# What would be a passive way to indicate the start of a new lecture in a document?

Tags: layout

I'm working on a LaTeX template for lecture notes. The template follows the `book` class and everything is fine. I have decided to only use headers, for showing the current section of the chapter and the page number.

Hence I'm unsure of how to indicate the starting point of a new lecture. I want it to be like a checkpoint or something which would indicate the lecture number along with the date on which the lecture was taken.
I don't wish to use a footer for this since I'd like to exactly pinpoint the section from where the new lecture started as all the lectures are built together, with no new lecture starting from a new page.

Since I'm new to LaTeX, I don't know if something of this sort already exists. At least a preliminary search said otherwise.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're looking for.  Do you have something in mind, but don't know how to implement it in LaTeX?  Or are you asking what would be possible to do in LaTeX?  The short answer to the latter question is "anything": a symbol in the margin, a horizontal line in the text, a very visible block of text produced by `\section{Lecture 14}`, ....  What do you want to have?

Comment: I'm actually asking suggestions on how to indicate certain checkpoints in any kind of document so that it doesn't steal unnecessary attention. And that I'd like to implement that approach using LaTeX.

Comment: The problem is that "suggestions" and "unnecessary attention" are somewhat subjective, and this site doesn't deal well with objective.  If you have something in mind, we'll be happy to help.  If you're looking for ideas, this may end up getting closed.

Comment: `\marginpar{\fbox{Lecture 14}}`

Comment: I guess I could use @Fran 's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in my notes is to just organize the material so that a lecture is (more or less) a (longish) section or a (short) chapter. Might even go for chapters and tweak the chapter header to say e.g. "Lecture 14".

You want each lecture to be self-contained, no loose ends. Exactly what you expect of a section or chapter. As a bonus, a section/chapter end is an ideal place for a summary, exercises or other non-lecture material.

Comment: I don't wish to make it a section. Rather I wish for it to be something indicated on the side.